# Svelte (rollup) - Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)

Tags: svelte, rollup

I am doing **nothing** to trigger this error. The app works fine one second, and doesn't the next.

Why is this happening? It is not due to the missing `@rollup/plugin-json` plugin because it worked previously without it.

## Error

```
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
path (imported by  path?commonjs-external)
http (imported by  http?commonjs-external)
net (imported by  net?commonjs-external)
url (imported by  url?commonjs-external)
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
node_modules/mime-db/db.json (2:40)
1: {
2:   "application/1d-interleaved-parityfec": {
                                           ^
3:     "source": "iana"
4:   },
Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
    at error (/mnt/c/ivan/dev/lab/atlas-biotek/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:5265:30)
    at Module.error (/mnt/c/ivan/dev/lab/atlas-biotek/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:9835:16)
    at tryParse (/mnt/c/ivan/dev/lab/atlas-biotek/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:9716:23)
    at Module.setSource (/mnt/c/ivan/dev/lab/atlas-biotek/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:10142:19)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (/mnt/c/ivan/dev/lab/atlas-biotek/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18312:20)
```

## Adding the plugin

```
npm i @rollup/plugin-json --save-dev
```

**rollup.js.config**

```js
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";

export default {
    plugins: [
        commonjs(),
        json(),      // <---- put after commonjs
    ]
}
```

## Client error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require$$0$1 is not defined
    at main.js:5
(anonymous) @ main.js:5
```

[image: UNCAUGHT]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I was importing a node module in the client due to autocomplete.

```js
import { is } from "express/lib/request";
```

Comment: In my case vscode autocompleted `  import { width } from "tailwindcss/lib/plugins";` It took some time to figure it out.

Comment: Then how do I use modules in the client without causing the error?

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Typescript, I added the `json()` plugin after `typescript`:

File: **rollup.config.js**

```js
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";


const plugins = [
  typescript({
    tsconfig: "./tsconfig-build.json",
  }),
  json(), <<------------- HERE
  resolve(),
  commonjs(),
  replace({
    ...
    preventAssignment: true,
  }),
];
```